# Multiple asyncs in discord.py but only first one is working

Tags: discord.py

So i startet today with python and wanted to code a discord bot. Now I ran into that problem that I have 4 asyncs all of them back to back but only the first one is working.

````
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="$")

async def Member(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.send("||@Member||")

async def Supporter(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.send("||@Supporter||")

async def everyone(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.send("||@everyone||")```
````

Answer (score 0):

So, I think you might be new to this. But when we post questions here we provide the code along with an error if there is one. Otherwise, how are we going to know your issue. But I am going to try to guess. Your bot.start() before the other functions because if so, the bot wont recognize them.

Needs to be like this.

```
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
@bot.command()
async def setdefaultrole(ctx, defualtRole):
     guildID = ctx.guild.id
     updateDefualtRole(guildID, defualtRole)

################################ Add Defualt Role ##################################################
     
#@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
#@bot.command()
#async def setdefualtrole(ctx, defualtRole):
     #guildID = ctx.guild.id
     #updateDefualtRole(guildID, defualtRole)
     
bot.run("TOKEN")
```

See how the bot.run() or bot.start() is at the bottom of all the functions. If this is not the problem, then add a code snippet from your code and then at me. Good luck.

Comment: Hi so ye im new and thank you for the Information and here is my Code
import discord

import os

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="$")

async def Member(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.send("||@Member||")

async def Supporter(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.send("||@Supporter||")

async def everyone(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.send("||@everyone||")

Weird formatted I don't know how to format it like you did.

Comment: @Peppy I cant really understand that code because its all jumbled together. Just edit your original question and then click on the code formatting button and paste your code in. Sorry its just since python is a tabbed based programing language its hard to read that. O yeah I just read that you didn't know how to format it.

Comment: ok I did that thank you btw you are really helping me. So when I type $Member it works but when I want to do $Supporter or $everyone it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

So the answer to this question for anyone in the future. He need to add bot.command() to every new command he was trying to make. Otherwise, it will not register as a command.

New code:

```
@bot.command()
async def Member(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.send("||@Member||")

@bot.command()
async def Supporter(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.send("||@Supporter||")

@bot.command()
async def everyone(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.send("||@everyone||")
```